# PHP MAMP user not finding /usr/local/bin

Tags: macos, apache, php, mamp

I have a website in a shared Linux hosting that uses Ghostscript. I use by php exec function that executes command line functions, gs commands to render PDF files, by simple gs commands.

```
gs -h (will display info)
```

However, in my Mac OS X MAMP web server gs commands are only executed by full paths.

```
/usr/local/bin/gs -h (will display info)
```

How do I configure my local system so "php" user will find gs (and other libraries) without full path?

EDIT: Command line by Terminal does not need full path either. The problem is only when trying to execute gs by exec PHP function.

Comment: Maybe useful [How to set $PATH in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550449/how-to-set-path-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely an issue with the default search path on MacOS X not including that directory. Homebrew is affected by that as well, so they list a workaround on their [FAQ](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md) page:

```
launchctl setenv PATH "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

That FAQ entry also helpfully references https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x/5444960 for more details about setting environment in OS X.

Comment: Ok, but when running the gs command by Terminal the gs is found, the problem is when using php exec function. The setenv will set the path for all users?